# Can't reach localhost urls provided when running docker images

Tags: python-3.x, docker, networking, jupyter-notebook, port

When I try to run a docker container that starts jupyter with os command inside a script or a neo4J docker image I have a network issue. I either have ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED or ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

## ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED

Whe I run jupyter notebook it seems everything is working right in the terminal:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix seriousgame:latest
Run bokeh server? ([y]/n) 
n
Run jupyter server? ([y]/n) 
y
[I 10:14:20.667 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 2021-12-13 10:14:20.942 LabApp] 'allow_root' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-12-13 10:14:20.942 LabApp] 'allow_root' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2021-12-13 10:14:20.945 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-12-13 10:14:20.945 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/serious-game
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.6 is running at:
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=Ihavetohidethis,right?
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=Ihavetohidethis,right?
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 10:14:20.950 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 10:14:20.950 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=Ihavetohidethis,right?
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=Ihavetohidethis,right?
```

But none of the links work ... I think it is because jupyter can't be reached from the Docker image. Because when I did it from the machine where there is jupyter I can access the notebook:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

In the requirements there is jupyterlab, I don't know if it is enough:

```
bash-5.1$ cat requirements.txt 
bokeh
jupyterlab
matplotlib
networkx
pandas
scipy
```

The Dockerfile for sure downloads the requirements:

```
bash-5.1$ cat Dockerfile 
#############################################################################################################
#
#   Creation du container
#
##############################################################################################################

FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04
MAINTAINER me

EXPOSE 5006
EXPOSE 8888

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV WD=/home/serious-game/
WORKDIR ${WD}


# Add git and ssh
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install git ssh pkg-config python3-pip python3-opencv

# Dépendances python
COPY requirements.txt  /requirements.txt
RUN cd / && \
     python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN ls
COPY start.py /start.py
CMD ["/start.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

So it seems to be a network error because when I tried to move the notebook from the container's localhost I still have the error "This site can’t be reached" ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED.

```
inpt = input("Run jupyter server? ([y]/n) \n")
if inpt.upper() in ["YES", "Y", ""]:
    os.system("jupyter-notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root")
    return
```

Here is the full output:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -p 8888:8888 seriousgame:latest
Run bokeh server? ([y]/n) 
n
Run jupyter server? ([y]/n) 

[I 09:45:21.148 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 2021-12-16 09:45:21.416 LabApp] 'allow_root' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-12-16 09:45:21.416 LabApp] 'allow_root' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2021-12-16 09:45:21.418 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-12-16 09:45:21.419 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/serious-game
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.6 is running at:
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=addd2ba3162ec37688def2cf63157864cd40b81cf4de42f8
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=addd2ba3162ec37688def2cf63157864cd40b81cf4de42f8
[I 09:45:21.422 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 09:45:21.424 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 09:45:21.424 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=addd2ba3162ec37688def2cf63157864cd40b81cf4de42f8
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=addd2ba3162ec37688def2cf63157864cd40b81cf4de42f8
```

## ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Interestingly, I have a similar network problem with when running a neo4j Docker image I can't reach the neo4j docker image that I tried to run:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run neo4j
^[[1;5C2021-12-16 09:55:17.973+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-12-16 09:55:18.312+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{d3a250fb} (d3a250fb-24b6-400d-82d2-5ff00740060f)
2021-12-16 09:55:19.163+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.4.1 ========
2021-12-16 09:55:20.406+0000 INFO  Initializing system graph model for component 'security-users' with version -1 and status UNINITIALIZED
2021-12-16 09:55:20.410+0000 INFO  Setting up initial user from defaults: neo4j
2021-12-16 09:55:20.411+0000 INFO  Creating new user 'neo4j' (passwordChangeRequired=true, suspended=false)
2021-12-16 09:55:20.422+0000 INFO  Setting version for 'security-users' to 3
2021-12-16 09:55:20.425+0000 INFO  After initialization of system graph model component 'security-users' have version 3 and status CURRENT
2021-12-16 09:55:20.429+0000 INFO  Performing postInitialization step for component 'security-users' with version 3 and status CURRENT
2021-12-16 09:55:20.739+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2021-12-16 09:55:21.298+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-12-16 09:55:21.300+0000 INFO  id: 6A9C435FEE30E82F3EF0611B5D98AB44CCF970739EA66D61896B3C801FA2A2B7
2021-12-16 09:55:21.300+0000 INFO  name: system
2021-12-16 09:55:21.301+0000 INFO  creationDate: 2021-12-16T09:55:19.614Z
2021-12-16 09:55:21.301+0000 INFO  Started.
```

And I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image]

I will test a Django webapp and add the results.

Maybe there is an issue in the IP addr?

```
bash-5.1$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:79:cc:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:6e:e0:f0:32:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.178/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp5s0
       valid_lft 168207sec preferred_lft 168207sec
    inet6 fe80::41c7:dafd:7a6:4f44/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:20:72:95:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:20ff:fe72:9551/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.254.99/24 brd 192.168.254.255 scope global noprefixroute tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7be4:d988:98c1:8551/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: veth6503edf@if17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether c2:c7:b8:5f:39:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::c0c7:b8ff:fe5f:396f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## So I can't reach the urls so far, other ideas?

### The volume is not the safe one?

The colleague who left me this image tells me that the working directory must be mounted as a volume.

```
bash-5.1$ docker run -p 8888:8888 -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /home/ac/Documents/Work/serious-game seriousgame:latest
```

But same error

And it seems it serves the right directory, right?

```
[I 2021-12-13 10:14:20.945 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 10:14:20.948 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/serious-game
```

### With the container port visible from the outside

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix seriousgame:latest
```

Pero aqui esta lo que me contesta el navigador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Issues in the IP addr?

```
bash-5.1$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:79:cc:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:6e:e0:f0:32:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.178/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp5s0
       valid_lft 168207sec preferred_lft 168207sec
    inet6 fe80::41c7:dafd:7a6:4f44/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:20:72:95:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:20ff:fe72:9551/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.254.99/24 brd 192.168.254.255 scope global noprefixroute tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7be4:d988:98c1:8551/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: veth6503edf@if17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether c2:c7:b8:5f:39:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::c0c7:b8ff:fe5f:396f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: The error message is not complaining about Bokeh or any library dependencies. It is saying *your app code* that is supposed to be locate at `serious_game/web_app/dash` is missing.

Comment: THanks @bigreddot  And what about the url not found? It seems it was up and running, isn't it?

Comment: That error means the Bokeh server has aborted / did not ever start. But I guess you are mapping the jupyter port for docker? No idea why that would not show up unless it also did not start, or started on a different port.

Comment: Yes I am mapping the jupyter port for Docker. My guess would have been because it didn't start but it seems it does from the very first output I pasted @bigreddot I am desesperate atm :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add  `--ip 0.0.0.0` to the jupyter notebook command, or it will serve on the container's localhost, which is not reachable from your host.

Also my 2 cents:
I would strongly advise to create a docker-compose file to tidy things up, build/run container easily, with something like :

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    image: seriousgame:latest
    build: .
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}
    volumes:
      - .:/home/serious-game/
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

I usually use Makefiles too, with make as ENTRYPOINT, then you only have to run your Makefile target using :

```sh
docker-compose run app {serve_bokeh,serve_jupiter,sh}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ludwig. I tried `docker run -p 8888:8888 -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /home/ac/Documents/Work/serious-game:/fuck --ip 0.0.0.0 seriousgame:latest` but I still have the same error ...

Comment: The `--ip 0.0.0.0` need to be set on the jupyter notebook command inside your start.py script.

Comment: Thanks for the advises Ludwig. I just to set it on the jupyter notebook command and I still have the error "This site can’t be reached" ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED."

Comment: Show the logs, everything after you launched the container.

Comment: Sure, I just added it. Today I tried to run a neo4J image with docker and the web address (http://localhost:7474/) is unreachable as well. I will add the docker run neo4j command output as well

Comment: Oh I see, as in the logs, jupyter still runs on 127.0.0.1 in the container because it's using an old start.py script, you need to rebuild the image, the logs should then display 0.0.0.0 all over the place.

About the volume, I guess your colleague meant a bind volume, like this : `-v /home/ac/Documents/Work/serious-game:/home/serious-game/` so the volume on your host is reflected inside the container at runtime, this would have prevented the above issue, but at this is optionnal now.

For your issue with neo4j, you need to expose the `-p 7687:7687` so it's reachable from the host.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I had to rebuild the image indeed. I am looking forward to learn how to create a Makefiles too with make as ENTRYPOINT